# How to receive data from one part of api to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

Alright, so I am trying to get this api work. The problem is that I don't know how to receive some data having a link to it at other part of this api.

The api itself looks like this:

```
{
  product
     {
       id,
       title,
       relationship:{
                      seller: sellerId
                    }
     }
 seller{
       company,
       seller: seller
       name: name
        }

}
```

So this sellerId and seller are identical. How can I link them together?

I've already got to show the sellerId, but I need to show the name itself using the sellerId.
I tried this:

```
render(){
        const { card, names } = this.props;
        const items = card.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <li key={index} className='list-group-item card'>
                    <ListItem 
                        name = { item.relationships.seller }
                        title = { item.title }
                        price = { item.price }
                        pictures = { item.pictures }/>
                </li>
            );
        })

        return (
            <ul className='list-group'>
                { items }
            </ul>
        )
    }
```

```
state = {
        item: [],
        names: []
    }
```

Comment: Is the object shown a GraphQL API request? Or the parsed response of another type of API?

Comment: parsed response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to merge the data from two arrays of objects (products and sellers), then you could use this:

```js
// the function to merge the objects
function mergeObjects(product, seller) {
  if (seller.seller === product.relationship.seller) {
    return Object.assign(seller, product)
  }
}

// for single objects:
const seller = sellerId = 'Seller'

const product1 = {
  id: 1,
  title: 'title1',
  relationship: {
    seller: sellerId
  }
}
const seller1 = {
  company: 'company1',
  seller: seller,
  name: 'name1'
}

console.log('single objects:', mergeObjects(product1, seller1))

// for arrays of objects
const sellerArr1 = sellerIdArr1 = 'sellerArr1'
const sellerArr2 = sellerIdArr2 = 'sellerArr2'

const products = [{
    id: 1,
    title: 'title1',
    relationship: {
      seller: sellerIdArr1
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'title2',
    relationship: {
      seller: sellerIdArr2
    }
  }
]

const sellers = [{
    company: 'company1',
    seller: sellerArr1,
    name: 'name1'
  },
  {
    company: 'company2',
    seller: sellerArr2,
    name: 'name2'
  }
]

const withArrays = sellers.map((e, i) => {
  return mergeObjects(products.filter(el => el.relationship.seller === e.seller)[0], e)
})

console.log('arrays:', withArrays)
```

With this solution you'll get only **one** array, and you can use the values of a single object.